# How to make a word underline in Markdown

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

How to make a word underline in Markdown?

For example: bold = `**bold**` or `__bold__`, italic = `*Italic*` or `_Italic_`.

I have tried with 2 and 3 underscores, but it is not working. Also tried by taking the reference of `markdown-it.js`.

Comment: Markdown doesn't have underline, see e.g. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/207727/why-there-is-no-markdown-for-underline

Comment: Try using `++Underline Me++`  markdown-it.js documentation has this.

Comment: For bold =__bold__ or **bold** and Italic = _Italic_ or *Italic*
I have tried

Comment: tried ++underline me++ is also not working .

Comment: @RENUSINGH Are you using `markdown-it.js` for parsing ? Or you just took the syntax reference from there. If you are not using `markdown-it.js` then I guess it won't work. Or you can try using the standard _HTML_ `<u>` tag and see if it works.

Comment: I am not using markdown-it.js. It's just syntax over here ....

Answer (score 31):

In Jupyter notebook, you can use the following to get underscored text

```
<u>underscored text </u>
```

Comment: This seems to be supported by Github

Answer (score 25):

since markdown is a markup language and In fact you can use HTML/CSS inside it, the easiest way I've found so far is:

```html
text here <span style="text-decoration: underline">underlined text</span> other text
```

**Note:** you can still use markdown syntax inside the `<span>` tag.

Comment: This worked for me! Is there a reason why someone wouldn't want to use this?

Comment: probably some people may want to keep things as clean as possible, using html somehow is like a walk around.

Comment: to help keep it clean you can use a CSS class  `.underline-me {text-decoration: underline;}`

Comment: "Is there a reason why someone wouldn't want to use this?"  Yeah, because it hasn't worked in any markdown form I've ever come across, Github being the prime example.  And maybe because your workaround is so cumbersome?

 It really blows my mind how anybody does not see that this is needed.

Comment: @zylstra pretty sure that person was just asking if there were any downsides to this method, not saying that this must be the only solution

Answer (score 14):

you can just use HTML markups in **mark down.**

if you want to underline, italic or strong, use follows,

```
<u> this is underlined </u> 

<i> this is italic </i> 

<strong> this is strong </strong>
```

etc..

Comment: This does not work in standard markdown.

Comment: I tried it in Google colab with Python and it works

Comment: Works in Marked 2, and in vim/nvim's MarkdownPreview plugin, fwiw.

Answer (score 5):

#### Using a plugin (`markdown-it-ins`)

You can use `++Underlined Text++` to make text underlined in `markdown-it.js`. Bear in mind that this is **not standard markdown** and might not work elsewhere. [Here](https://markdown-it.github.io/#md3=%7B%22source%22%3A%22%2B%2BUderlined%20text%2B%2B%22%2C%22defaults%22%3A%7B%22html%22%3Afalse%2C%22xhtmlOut%22%3Afalse%2C%22breaks%22%3Afalse%2C%22langPrefix%22%3A%22language-%22%2C%22linkify%22%3Atrue%2C%22typographer%22%3Atrue%2C%22_highlight%22%3Atrue%2C%22_strict%22%3Afalse%2C%22_view%22%3A%22html%22%7D%7D)'s a demonstration of this working in the `markdown-it` website.

This syntactic extension (inserted text) is added by a plugincalled [markdown-it-ins](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it-ins). It's enabled by default in the demo page, but you might need to install and enable it manually for your own page.

#### Using HTML tags inside markdown

If you want this to work for any markdown parser, you should try using the `<u>` HTML tag, as most parsers will actually parse HTML inside markdown (**this might cause a few unwanted side-effects**). `markdown-it` supports it, if you enable the related option. [Here](https://markdown-it.github.io/#md3=%7B%22source%22%3A%22Normal%20markdown%20%3Cu%3Eunderlined%20text%3C%2Fu%3E%2C%20%2A%2Abold%20text%2A%2A%20etc.%22%2C%22defaults%22%3A%7B%22html%22%3Atrue%2C%22xhtmlOut%22%3Afalse%2C%22breaks%22%3Afalse%2C%22langPrefix%22%3A%22language-%22%2C%22linkify%22%3Atrue%2C%22typographer%22%3Atrue%2C%22_highlight%22%3Atrue%2C%22_strict%22%3Afalse%2C%22_view%22%3A%22html%22%7D%7D)'s an example of this in action.

Comment: This doesn't work in stackoverflow's markdown, for example. At the very least, it's non-standard.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  you're right about that. I am looking for actual documentation to support this. I know it works in `markdown-it.js`, because I have used it and tried it just now, however I cannot find the documentation for it.

Comment: @AngelosChalaris It's there on there [demo page](https://markdown-it.github.io/), but couldn't find any documentation related to this.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia Thanks for mentioning this, it helped me identify where it comes from (a plugin for inserted text).

Answer (score 1):

I was actually looking for a workaround and though the use of a **<u>** HTML tag can be regularly interpreted by a Markdown parser, I ***changed my point of view*** and understood that I could do without it.
After all, Markdown is all about simplifying the documentation and levelling it out so that every document could be ***equally read***.
i.e. if I want to use Markdown I'll stick to its principles.

By the way, this answer has been formatted with the help of Markdown itself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement on the answers, if you happen to be using Atom for the markdown, `++this++` won't work (unless perhaps if you install any package for that), but `<u>this</u>` will.

Answer (score 0):

I have:

```
output:
   pdf_document:
      latex_engine: xelatex
      keep_tex: true
```

in-line, outside of chunk:

```
\underline{Text to Underline}
```

and it works just fine!

Comment: This is specific to quarto / rmarkdown and OP doesn't appear to be using those.